# Styling my Table fetched from SQL DB

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and thus looking for an easy and quick solution.
A SQL table should be displayed on my website and I need to style only **one** of the table rows (the second one: "Betrag"). As far as I understood, the table row is created here:

```
 function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>";
```

I'm not sure though how to style only one of them instead of all the  together. Is this even possible with my code?
Thanks for your help!

```
   <?php
echo "<table style='width: 60%; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;text-align: center;' >";
echo "<tr><th>Text</th><th>Betrag</th><th>Zeichen</th><th>Datum</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='background-color: #F7F7F7;padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; border:1px solid white;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Inhalt, Betrag, Zeichen, Datum FROM korrektur_user1 ORDER BY Inhalt DESC"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: By "style" do you mean applying CSS to your HTML? Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes exactly. Just like where the  `<td>` is created, I want to add CSS styles to the `<tr>`, but **only to one of them**.

Comment: You can use javascript/jquery to add styles to any of the table rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're styling the table in your PHP file, which is bad practice.
Create a separate CSS file and style it from there, for example with `td:nth-child(2) {background: #ff0000;}`

Or do:

```
echo "<tr><th>Text</th>"; ?> 
<th style="STYLE HERE">Betrag</th>
<?php
echo "<th>Zeichen</th><th>Datum</th></tr>"; ?>
```

Comment: I will look into this solution `td:nth-child(2) {background: #ff0000;}`, never used this method before.
The second solution only styles the header of the row, that's nice but not exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out `id` HTML attribute. You can add those ids to your table rows and get something like:

```
<tr id="qwerty">
    ...
</tr>
<tr id="betrag">
    ...
</tr>
<tr id="kljhlkh">
    ...
</tr>
```

Then, in your CSS file (or just in the same HTML file, in a `<style>` tag):

```
tr#betrag {
    /*your styles here*/
}
```

This makes sure that only "betrag" row gets styled.

Alternatively, if you need to style second row regardless of its content, use [nth child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment above, edit your PHP script:

```
function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr class='someClass'>"; 
    }
```

In your CSS,

```
tr.someClass {
  /* Add your stylistic declaration here */
}
```

Or, and less recommended, do everything in your PHP

```
function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr style='background:#666666;'>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I add the class to this line `echo "<tr class='someClass'>"; ` , wouldn't it apply to all the table rows?